# How to group a list of numbers into certain categories

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to take in a list of numbers and sort them into certain categories such as 0-10, 10-20, 20-30 and up to 90-100 but I have the code started, but the code isn't reading in all the inputs, but only the last one and repeating it. I am stumped, anyone help please?

```
def eScores(Scores):

    count0 = 0
    count10 = 0
    count20 = 0
    count30 = 0
    count40 = 0
    count50 = 0
    count60 = 0
    count70 = 0
    count80 = 0
    count90 = 0

    if Scores > 90:
        count90 = count90 + 1
    if Scores > 80:
        count80 = count80 + 1
    if Scores > 70:
        count70 = count70 + 1
    if Scores > 60:
        count60 = count60 + 1
    if Scores > 50:
        count50 = count50 + 1
    if Scores > 40:
        count40 = count40 + 1
    if Scores > 30:
        count30 = count30 + 1
    if Scores > 20:
        count20 = count20 + 1
    if Scores > 10:
        count10 = count10 + 1
    if Scores <= 10:
        count0 = count0 + 1

    print count90,'had a score of (90 - 100]'
    print count80,'had a score of (80 - 90]'
    print count70,'had a score of (70 - 80]'
    print count60,'had a score of (60 - 70]'
    print count50,'had a score of (50 - 60]'
    print count40,'had a score of (40 - 50]'
    print count30,'had a score of (30 - 40]'
    print count20,'had a score of (20 - 30]'
    print count10,'had a score of (10 - 20]'
    print count0,'had a score of (0 - 10]'    

    return eScores(Scores)
```

Comment: a better approach would be to use an array to store the counts, and then just divide the number by 10 to see which bucket it falls in to...

Comment: My code will return this "TypeError: eScores() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)". Yes I am new to python, anyone direct me in the right direction as to why this is happening and possibly showing where in the code its forcing this, thanks.

Comment: @user1249113: the `TypeError` you're talking about is not a result of the code you're showing.  How are you calling the function?

Comment: I am calling the function within the python shell itself, by doing eScore(5,15,25,35,etc.) testing it out.

Comment: @user1249113 eScore() only accepts one input, `Scores`. But you are trying to pass it several, `eScore(5,15,25,35,etc.)` If you want to allow multiple inputs treat `Scores` as a [array](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) and pass in a list like: `eScore([5,15,25,35,etc.])` (note the brackets)

Comment: Show the part where you "read" the input (i.e. create the list of scores and then pass it to the function). I see no list of data here.

Answer (score 1):

Each time `eScores` is called is sets all the counters (`count10`, `count20`) back to zero. So only the final call has any effect.

You should either declare the counters as global variables, or put the function into a class and make the counters member variables of the class.

Another problem is that the function calls itself in the `return` statement:

```
return eScores(Scores)
```

Since this function is (as I understand it) supposed to update the counter variables only, it does not need to return anything, let alone call itself recursively. You'd better remove the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you're making a mistake on is that you're not breaking out of the whole set of if's when you go through.  For example, if you're number is 93 it is going to set count90 to 1, then go on to count80 and set that to one as well, and so on until it gets to count10.

Comment: I see that now. How can I break out of that and not allow that to happen? Just wondering.

Comment: What would be the easiest way, I mean.

Comment: Don't just keep using 'if', rather use 'elif'

Answer (score 0):

Your code is repeating because the function is infintely recursive (it has no stop condition).  Here are the relevant bits:

```
def eScores(Scores):
    # ...
    return eScores(Scores)
```

I think what you'd want is more like:

```
def eScores(Scores):
    # same as before, but change the last line:
    return
```

Since you're printing the results, I assume you don't want to return the values of `score10`, `score20`, etc.

Also, the function won't accumulate results since you're creating new local counts each time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use each number as a key (after processing) and return a dictionary of values?

```
def eScores(Scores):
    return_dict = {}
    for score in Scores:
        keyval = int(score/10)*10 # py3k automatically does float division
        if keyval not in return_dict:
            return_dict[keyval] = 1
        else:
            return_dict[keyval] += 1
    return return_dict
```